# Where is System.Buffers.Binary?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've been advised to use [BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives) class but when I look for the assemblies I cannot find either:

- System.Memory.dll
- netstandard.dll

[image]

When I look closely at the docs it is only listed against .Net Core and .Net Standard but I didn't think those libraries had functionality *not* in .Net Framework. Is this simply not available to me? We haven't switched as a company to .Net Core yet.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/ There is also some additional dependencies for .NET Framework

Comment: *When I look closely at the docs it is only listed against .Net Core and .Net Standard but I didn't think those libraries had functionality not in .Net Framework* You thought wrong. [.NET Framework does not implement .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)

Comment: I wish MS would say in their docs that it's available for Framework via Nuget! Combining your two comments combined is basically an authoritative answer...

Comment: As a general rule, any `System.*` or `Microsoft.*` libraries that are in Core/Standard but not Framework, are available as NuGet packages for Framework.

Answer (score 0):

> When I look closely at the docs it is only listed against .Net Core and .Net Standard but I didn't think those libraries had functionality not in .Net Framework.

You thought wrong. [.NET Framework does not implement .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

The `BinaryPrimitives` class is available on nuget: [nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/)

<sub><sub>This answer is taken from the comments on the question</sub></sub>